# Problems with Scrapy and reuters.com

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

I have a problem with Scrapy and Reuters. Following the example  given on page https://realpython.com/blog/python/web-scraping-and-crawling-with-scrapy-and-mongodb/ I want to do the same with http://www.reuters.com/news/archive/businessNews?view=page&page=1, ie. after downloading the information from the first page, I want to download information from the following pages, but LinkExtractor function does not work properly. Here is my code

```
class ReutersCrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'reuters_crawler'
allowed_domains = ['www.reuters.com',]
start_urls = [
    "http://www.reuters.com/news/archive/businessNews?page=1&pageSize=10&view=page",
]

rules = [
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'\?page=[0-9]&pageSize=10&view=page', restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pageNavigation"]',)),
         callback='parse_item', follow=True)
]

def parse_item(self, response):
    questions = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="feature"]/h2')

    for question in questions:
        item = ReutersItem()
        item['title'] = question.xpath('a/text()').extract()[0]
        item['timeextraction'] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
        yield item
```

Where are making a mistake? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

try following code to scrap intended items:

class ReutersCrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'reuters_crawler'

```
allowed_domains = ['www.reuters.com',]
start_urls = ["http://www.reuters.com/news/archive/businessNews?view=page&page=%s" % page for page in xrange(1,10)]

'''rules = [ Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'\?page=[0-9]&pageSize=10&view=page', restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pageNavigation"]',)),
     callback='parse_item', follow=True)]'''

def parse(self, response):
    questions = Selector(response).xpath('.//div[@class="feature"]/h2')

    for question in questions:
        item = ReutersItem()
        item['title'] = question.xpath('a/text()').extract()[0]
        item['timeextraction'] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
        yield item
```

Comment: Ok, I know this trick, but  what is the reason for the existence of LinkExtractor and Rule?

Answer (score 0):

The meaning for the `Rule`s and the `LinkExtractor`s is that you have a main site which has URLs but not the contents you want to scrape. For this you could write the `parse` method and extract every URL on the page manually and filter them to new `Request` objects -- or you can use a `Rule` to extract specified links with the `LinkExtractor` to match the `allow` filter and which can be found in the `restrict_xpaths` block. Then Scrapy will create automatically new `Request` objects out of those links and call the `callback` method with the `Response`s of those `Request`s.

If you look at the HTML source of the website you try to crawl you can see that it has some JavaScript which creates the `class="pageNavigation"` `div`s. This means when you try to parse the site with Scrapy you do not find the specified class to restrict the XPath to.

We can use for this the `parse` method which parses the result of the `start_urls`:

```
def parse(self, response):
    print response.xpath('//div[@class="pageNavigation"]')
```

This produces an empty list on the console. This means that no `div` is present with the `class` `pageNavigation` in the `Respone`'s body. So the Rule won't work.

To solve this problem you could utilize a manual solution to extract the next URL from the JavaScript code -- or simply create a request in the `parse` method with the next page number -- until you encounter a "Not found" site.

```
current_page = 1
def parse(self, response):
    questions = Selector(response).xpath('.//div[@class="feature"]/h2')

    for question in questions:
        item = ReutersItem()
        item['title'] = question.xpath('a/text()').extract()[0]
        item['timeextraction'] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
        yield item
    self.current_page += 1
    yield Request("http://www.reuters.com/news/archive/businessNews?page={0}&pageSize=10&view=page".format(self.current_page))
```

And by the way: the current questions get the "Politics video" and "Front row Washington" with every site. You should restrict this in your implementation.